# Prevent stdin wait for first message from named pipe

Tags: pipe, fifo

I need to communicate with a background process via a named pipe. This background process is a node.js process.

So I do this in a shell script:

```
mkfifo MYPIPE
node script.js < MYPIPE
```

what happens is that the node.js script does not start - it appears to be waiting for the first stdin message to be written to `MYPIPE`.

What I want to do, is send the data from MYPIPE to the stdin of the node process, but I want to start the node.js process instead of it waiting for the first message from MYPIPE. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was just a simple case of doing this instead:

```
cat MYPIPE | node script.js
```

I guess I just don't understand why that behaves differently than

```
node script.js < MYPIPE
```

Comment: and maybe I need to add an option to cat, so that it continues to read from the named pipe.